# ClassCastException on custom object with child objects which is parcelable

Tags: java, android

Good day,

I was assigned to an android project inside my company and I'm having a little bit of a struggle. I have not touched Android in a few years. Figured you might be able to help me find what i am missing.

I have a project that calls an external libratry for reading a barcode, then the code does a parsing of the byte array and converts it into an object. The problem I am having is of comunication between my MainActivity and the activity that scans the barcode.

This is the piece of code that calls my barcode reader activity:

---

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MyObjectActivity.setParentActivity(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyObjectActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

---

This one should escalate the scanned data from  MyObjectActivity object into my MainActivity (so i can actually do something with the data).

---

```
try
        {
        //MyObject objet contains child objects
            MyObject content = MyObjectParser.retrieveContentData(data /*contains the byte array*/);
            Intent data_toreturn = new Intent();
            data_toreturn.putExtra("data_sent", true);
            data_toreturn.putExtra(BARCODE_DATA_EXTRA_TAG, content);

            if (getParent() == null)
            {                
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data_toreturn);
            } else
                getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, data_toreturn);
        } catch(final RuntimeException e)
        {
            parentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(parentActivity, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        // stop the Activity
        finish();
```

---

While debugging i manage to run all the code up until the finish(). Then i get the exception

Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {MyObjectActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to ChildObject[]

According to what I remember from developping in android, in order to be able to pass Objects between Activities you need intents and Objects that are Parcelable or Serializable (not sure about this one). I've reviewed the code and the sub objects DO implement this.

I really don't know how to continue. It is either a thing of configuration, or I am doing something very wrong and I am not seeing it.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: How are you getting the object from the intent? Do you do that by calling getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass"); method?

Answer (score 1):

So I see you are using

startActivityForResult(intent, Yournumber) //I would not use 0, use 1001 or something more custom.
so that you make yourself the parent of the launched activity.
So why are you doing the setParentActivity call? I assume just for doing your Toast? Seems like a unhealthy way to handle that, but that is a different issue.

Then override onActivityResult in that parent activity to handle the intent data returned. As I'm sure you have already done.

But I'm not certain of your "content" object if it is parcable or not. You can check by simply commenting out "adding that to the intent" and seeing if it gets delivered when that object is not inside the intent.

If it is delivered then you should ensure that your object implements Parceable so that it can be put in the intents. If it still does not get delivered then it would appear you are having an issue with your parent not pointing to the correct class somehow and we would need to see more code to help out on that.

I see you are passing the raw bytes, which should work fine, but you could try a wrapper object that implements parceable as well that holds the bytes as a member and pass back that object as a last ditch effort as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're sending an Object X via an explicit Intent from Activity A to Activity B.

Step 1 - make sure your class X implements Serializable interface (which you said you already have). Also make sure that all other objects inside your Object X do implement Serializable interface.

Step 2 - Somewhere inside your Activity A you'd have similar code:

```
X objectX = new X();
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("myObject", objectX);
startActivity(intent);
```

Step 3 - Inside your Activity B you will get the Object reference and typecast it to X:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
X objectX = (X)intent.getSerializableExtra("myObject");
```

Hope this helps. This is the basic pattern of passing objects between Activities and there is nothing more to it.